# ghc can't find the module it's trying to build

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have the latest packages on Arch, ghc 8.2.1 and cabal 2.0, trying to build ncurses package using cabal:

```
$ cabal configure
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring ncurses-0.2.16...
$ cabal build
Preprocessing library for ncurses-0.2.16..
Building library for ncurses-0.2.16..

<no location info>: error:
    module ‘UI.NCurses’ cannot be found locally
```

The said module are part of the package I am trying to build and its source files are located in lib directory. Everything seems to be specified in the cabal file, but why can't it find it?

I tried building it with runhaskell, but got same error.

part of cabal file:

```
extra-source-files:
  cbits/hsncurses-shim.c
  cbits/hsncurses-shim.h
  cbits/mavericks-c2hs-workaround.h

source-repository head
  type: git
  location: https://john-millikin.com/code/haskell-ncurses/

source-repository this
  type: git
  location: https://john-millikin.com/code/haskell-ncurses/
  tag: haskell-ncurses_0.2.16

-- Do not use default to using pkg-config to find ncurses libraries, because
-- the .pc files are missing or broken in many installations.
flag use-pkgconfig
  default: False
  manual: True
  description:
    Use pkg-config to set linker and include flags.

flag force-narrow-library
  default: False
  manual: True
  description:
    Force including and linking against ncurses instead of ncursesw. This is
    only useful on systems that have the ncursesw package installed
    incorrectly. On most systems this will cause compile- or run-time errors.
library
  hs-source-dirs: lib
  ghc-options: -Wall -O2
  include-dirs: cbits

  build-depends:
      base >= 4.6 && < 5.0
    , containers >= 0.2
    , text >= 0.7
    , transformers >= 0.2

  build-tools:
    c2hs >= 0.15

  if flag(use-pkgconfig)
    if flag(force-narrow-library)
      cc-options: -DHSNCURSES_NARROW_HEADER
      pkgconfig-depends: ncurses, panel
    else
      pkgconfig-depends: ncursesw, panelw
  else
    -- MacOS has a version of ncurses where the narrow- and wide-character
    -- builds have been merged into a single header/dylib.
    --
    -- Explicitly linking against libpthread.so fixes a build problem on
    -- platforms where the linker doesn't automatically follow dependencies.
    if os(darwin) || os(freebsd) || flag(force-narrow-library)
      cc-options: -DHSNCURSES_NARROW_HEADER
    if os(darwin) || flag(force-narrow-library)
      extra-libraries: panel ncurses pthread
    else
      extra-libraries: panelw ncursesw pthread

  c-sources: cbits/hsncurses-shim.c

  exposed-modules:
    UI.NCurses
    UI.NCurses.Panel

  other-modules:
    UI.NCurses.Enums
    UI.NCurses.Compat
    UI.NCurses.Types
```

Comment: Note that there is ``UI.NCurses.chs``, which needs to be preprocessed with `c2hs`. Although it is required by the `.cabal` file, could you check that you have `c2hs` installed on your path?

Comment: Yes. c2hs is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same Problem. A library I depended upon failed to install with the same error message despite of `c2hs` being installed and in the `PATH`.

The solution for me was to run `cabal clean` inside the project i wanted to build and reconfiguring it with `cabal configure`.

I suspect there was a hickup during a previous build process which leaved cabal to think `c2hs` ran properly, which in that case didn't.